# motivation of rewriting the form of chebyshev equation when trying to find the exponents of each of the singular point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am just wondering what are the motivation of writing the chebyshev equation in the following forms respectively when trying to find the exponent of each of the singular point: $x_1 = 1$, $x_2=-1$ respectively?

I was reading that to find the exponent for $x_1 = 1$, we do this:
[image]

and then to find the exponent for $x_2 = -1$, we do this:
[image]

But how do we come up with the forms written there?  (what are the reasoning or motivations of writing the equation like that?)

Comment: What book  is it  John ?

Comment: @Aryadeva Hi, it is not from a book, it is here: https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/the-chebyshev-equation-is1x2yxy2y0whereis-a-constant-see-problem-10-of-section-53a-show-that-x1-and/?fbclid=IwAR0yEwO2rG69WNzqgtwf0qr2IlEj3Pm2RTAJZ-qFuwAHlttF4HJmM_n47mo

Comment: @Aryadeva Is it possible to know the motivation behind the above two forms of writing the equation?

Comment: It's just a change of variable like series solution around  $z=0$ where $z=x+1$ for the second DE  and  $z=x-1$ for the first DE @john